# What is the pin state during microcontroller flashing?

Tags: microcontroller, gpio

I know that upon reset most micros put pins into high-z state. Is this state preserved during microcontroller flashing? What precautions need to be taken if you are going to reprogram microcontroller on your board with external devices powered and connected? Particularly I'm interested in STM32F4XX micros. Thanks

Comment: Do the datasheet and application notes not cover this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams can't find it, but I also want to understand design principles or flashing subsystem.

Comment: What kind of flashing are you refering to? IAP? ROM bootloader? JTAG?

Comment: If you write your own bootloader, you can configure the pins as needed.

Comment: @user3634713 I'm planning to use DFU flash, DFU flash program is factory programmed into ROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to use the ROM bootloader, the MCU will actually be running code. It is not like JTAG that can stop the processor. It is just that the code running is not yours.

This simply means that the chip will behave exactly as it does in normal operation, running your firmware.

To start the ROM bootloader you have to reset the MCU. This means that all registers will be at reset values, except those the ROM firmware changes. As it is obvious this factory firmware will only change the values at the registers it is needed to, so only the pins used by the bootloader will not have the reset value. All other pins I would expect to have the reset value.

If you are using pins that are used by the bootloader for different operation then you need a hardware multiplexer. If for example the bootloader uses some pins for UART communication, and the same pins are used by your application for controlling something else.

For the other pins, they will be in input mode. This is, beacuse it is a safe state for the MCU (you cannot short any of its GPIOs), but may not be safe for your application, as these pins may be floating.

Always (and not only because of the bootloader), you should add pull-up or pull-down resistors to define a default state for all your outputs, while the MCU is not able to control them.

Answer (score 2):

I think *generally* you could consider it a safe assumption that upon reset, all pins will be set as inputs.

However, even if the datasheet/app notes do not explicitly say this, look at the default values in the pin configuration registers. If your Port direction register resets to 0, and 0 means input, then it is safe to conclude that all pins will be inputs until set otherwise. Sometimes this information is not blatantly obvious. For example, Atmel (8-bit) datasheets tend to put the reset value of a particular register in small text, next to the register diagram.

If you wish to learn more about the flashing/reset process, the documentation is your best bet. My guess is that there exists an app note about downloading code to the microcontroller, probably geared towards setting up a production environment or developing an ICSP. As for reset conditions, that is likely covered in a chapter in the datasheet for the particular model or family of the microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

If I got this correctly. Here are the excerpts from datasheet that seem to make a picture:

During and just after reset, the alternate functions are not active and the I/O ports are configured in input floating mode. The debug pins are in AF pull-up/pull-down after reset:

- PA15: JTDI in pull-up
- PA14: JTCK/SWCLK in pull-down
- PA13: JTMS/SWDAT in pull-up
- PB4: NJTRST in pull-up
- PB3: JTDO in floating state

The embedded bootloader mode is used to reprogram the Flash memory using one of the
following serial interfaces:

- USART1(PA9/PA10)
- USART3(PB10/11 and PC10/11)
- CAN2(PB5/13)
- USB OTG FS(PA11/12) in Device mode (DFU: device firmware upgrade)

So I guess except for the listed pins, state of the rest pins can be enforced by pull-ups, pull-downs.